# Different styling for a thumbnail class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i took 3 thumbnail classes and for each class i want to give different styling like i want a border for them with different colors.I tried to change the class name and give the styling but its not working,the alignment is missing.Is there any other way.pls help me out.

Comment: Can you post your code to show what's you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the css class that provides the base styling `thumbnail` then add a class to create additional styling.  This is the purpose of cascading style sheets.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail border-green">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

In this example we add a class `border-green`.  Then you define that class in your css:

```
.border-green{
    border-color:green;
}
```

If you want `border-green` to only apply to `thumbnails` your css would be defined like this:

```
.thumbnail.border-green{
    border-color:green;
}
```